# Client-server message exchange - Sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to answer the clients message with an echo, but I am not figuring how to. My client sends a message, but then I reverse the papers and the program doesn't proceed (gets stuck in line

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

of the server). I guess it is about closing the inputstream, but when I do that, that closes the socket and I have no way to reuse it. I have managed do do this with readUTF and with socket.shutDownInput, but I want a easiest way - like close or flush, which I am not getting.

Client

```
public class SocketClient {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    // Check arguments
    if (args.length < 3) {
        System.err.println("Argument(s) missing!");
        System.err.printf("Usage: java %s host port file%n", SocketClient.class.getName());
        return;
    }

    String host = args[0];
    // Convert port from String to int
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    // Concatenate arguments using a string builder
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
        sb.append(args[i]);
        if (i < args.length-1) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    String text = sb.toString();

    // Create client socket
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    System.out.printf("Connected to server %s on port %d %n", host, port);

    // Create stream to send data to server
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    // Send text to server as bytes
    out.writeBytes(text);
    out.writeBytes("\n"); // devia meter readline a null...

    System.out.println("Sent text: " + text);

    System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + socket.getPort());

    //out.close();
    //socket.shutdownOutput(); trials...
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("here");
    // Receive data until client closes the connection
    String response;
    while ((response = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.printf("Received message with content: '%s'%n", response); // here is where client doesn't proceed - he doesn't get the echo
```

Server

```
public class SocketServer {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
// Check arguments
if (args.length < 1) {
System.err.println("Argument(s) missing!");
System.err.printf("Usage: java %s port%n", SocketServer.class.getName());
        return;
    }

    // Convert port from String to int
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    // Create server socket
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.printf("Server accepting connections on port %d %n", port);

    // wait for and then accept client connection
    // a socket is created to handle the created connection
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.printf("Connected to client %s on port %d %n",
        clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), clientSocket.getPort());

    // Create stream to receive data from client
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    // Receive data until client closes the connection
    String response;
    while ((response = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.printf("Received message with content: '%s'%n", response);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////


    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); // he doesn't reach here

    System.out.println("here-serv");

    System.out.println(clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + clientSocket.getPort());
    // Send text to server as bytes
    out.writeBytes("echo");
```

I actually believe this problem has something with the readline from server, it is not getting a null - but the client sends a "\n"! Can you find my code mistake? Thanks

Comment: I donot know much about sockets, but why dont you go for firebase cloud messaging in case you want to build a real time chat server ?

Comment: i don't want to build that, this is just an experiment. Simply making both sides sending and receiveing and that's it...

Comment: A socket will block until it is closed, and output streams should use `flush()`

Comment: I use flush but it remains stuck on ther server side...

Comment: ok I figured out that readline would never receive a null until the conection stream is closed... then that stoppage condition was overkill - only for send-and-close conections..